# Add Polygon with array of points

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, polygon

I have a set of markers created around an area and I want to join them together to create a polygon (and shade it). My polygon code:

```
                var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                  paths: points,
                  strokeColor: '#f33f00',
                  fillColor: '#ff99aa',
                  fillOpacity: 0.2
                });
                polygon.setMap(map);
```

Where I have

```
var points    = new Array();
points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(prev_dest.y, prev_dest.x));
```

Is the .push command no longer working in V3? Previously this worked:

```
map.addOverlay(new GPolygon(points, "#f33f00", 5, 1, "#ff99aa", 0.2));
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push is simply adding items to the array it has nothing to do with Google Maps API.

For a polygon to know its "closed" - make sure your first and last point in the array of points are the same - otherwise its not a valid polygon.

if its not simply add your fist point again to the array of points.

Comment: Thank you, turns out my lat and long were the wrong way round so it was plotting it in a different part of the world